# Create subset of data frame to indicate limits in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, ribbon

I am trying to fill between two lines in a plot but after several trials I still can´t figure out how to show in the code the specific area that I need to be shaded.

Here´s my dataset:

```
high
```

| Time | Trat | mean | sd | level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | HC | 27.26 | 6.19 | high |
| T1 | Control HC | 28.22 | 1.82 | high |
| T1 | HCc | 26.39 | 6.19 | high |
| T2 | HC | 32.81 | 0.84 | high |
| T2 | Control HC | 30.10 | 2.58 | high |
| T2 | HCc | 30.88 | 0.84 | high |
| T3 | HC | 35.15 | 3.93 | high |
| T3 | Control HC | 32.60 | 0.75 | high |
| T3 | HCc | 33.91 | 3.93 | high |
| T4 | HC | 38.60 | 3.50 | high |
| T4 | Control HC | 29.66 | 4.81 | high |
| T4 | HCc | 37.14 | 3.50 | high |
| T5 | HC | 41.71 | 1.47 | high |
| T5 | Control HC | 29.97 | 4.75 | high |
| T5 | HCc | 39.78 | 1.47 | high |
| T6 | HC | 41.07 | 0.32 | high |
| T6 | Control HC | 27.04 | 4.79 | high |
| T6 | HCc | 37.73 | 0.32 | high |
| T7 | HC | 43.55 | 0.71 | high |
| T7 | Control HC | 25.48 | 4.75 | high |
| T7 | HCc | 40.32 | 0.71 | high |
| T8 | HC | 45.71 | 2.62 | high |
| T8 | Control HC | 24.13 | 4.61 | high |
| T8 | HCc | 41.33 | 2.62 | high |
| T9 | HC | 47.57 | 1.65 | high |
| T9 | Control HC | 23.23 | 5.44 | high |
| T9 | HCc | 42.12 | 1.65 | high |
| T10 | HC | 51.53 | 4.40 | high |
| T10 | Control HC | 24.69 | 6.81 | high |
| T10 | HCc | 46.09 | 4.40 | high |

And here´s my code:

(I posted the full code just in case it´s needed but please ignore the parts that are not directly related to the question).

```
ggplot(high, aes(Time, mean, color=Trat,group = Trat))+
geom_line( aes( linetype=Trat, color=Trat), size=1.5, na.rm=T)+
    labs(x = ("Time (days)"), y = bquote("Clorophyll-a"~ (µg.L^-1))) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("T1", "T2","T3", "T4", "T5","T6","T7","T8","T9","T10"),labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))+
  theme_classic(base_size = 15)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 2))+
  scale_color_grey()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=1, position=position_dodge(.01))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=3))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=Time, ymax=x.upper, ymin=x.lower), fill="gray", alpha=.5)
```

I need the shaded area to be placed between HC and HCc lines. . [image]

How can I show in the code that the upper limit are HC mean values and the lower limit are HCc means?

I created separated vectors with the values but the code produces an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to pass a different data frame to the ribbon in wide format:

```r
ggplot(high, aes(Time, mean))+
geom_line( aes( linetype=Trat, color=Trat, group = Trat), size=1.5, na.rm=T)+
    labs(x = ("Time (days)"), y = bquote("Clorophyll-a"~ (µg.L^-1))) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("T1", "T2","T3", "T4", "T5","T6","T7","T8","T9","T10"),
                   labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))+
  theme_classic(base_size = 15)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(legend.position="right")+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  guides(col = guide_legend(nrow = 2))+
  scale_color_grey()+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd,
                    color=Trat,group = Trat), 
                width=1, position=position_dodge(.01))+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(nrow=3))+
  geom_ribbon(data = tidyr::pivot_wider(high,
                                        id_cols = c("Time", "Trat"), 
                                        names_from = "Trat", 
                                        values_from = c("mean", "sd")),
              aes(y = 1, ymax=mean_HCc, ymin=mean_HC, color = "HC", group = "HC"), 
              fill="gray", alpha=.5)
```

[image]

Comment: That´s exactly what I need but when I run the new piece of code I get several errors. Can you give me a more detailed explanation? Do I need to modify the original data frame? Are mean_HCc and mean_HC created automatically? I tried calling library(tidyr) but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Warning messages:
1: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
2: Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates 
> plot
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'mean_HCc' not found

Comment: Hi Patricia. It's not clear why you are getting the errors - I used exactly the data you included in the question to get the above result.  Could you perhaps edit your question to include your actual data frame? Just type `dput(high)` into the console and copy/paste the result into a code block - it should be easy to figure it out then.

Comment: I am posting this comment to finish the discussion since the previous comments that I posted seem to have been deleted. I closed and opened R again, reviewed the full code and it worked fine. Problem solved, thank you.